# Installation trouble - many unknown partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my new laptop, but I'm getting in trouble when I try to partition my disk.

Partition step in Ubuntu installer:

[image: Partition step]

GParted:

[image: GParted]

I should change the 500GB partition because that is the size of my SSD, but can I delete the 16MB partition to create a `/home` and a `/` partition? Also can I delete the Windows Boot Manager partition to put a swap instead?

Comment: If keeping windows, don't touch.  Swap partition not needed for 18.04 and after.  Go back and open windows and see how much free space it has.  16MB is not big enough for much use.  Place ubuntu on new partition created from free space from windows.  Need about 20GBs very minimum(just to run it, no downloading), but half or more of 500GBs be nice

Comment: @crip659 But i need 2 partition for the /home and the root, i can only create 2 actually, i need to delete one

Comment: @user68186 Done

Comment: Do you want to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu? Or delete Windows and just use Ubuntu? Please edit in the question. Also, when you boot from USB, are you using UEFI boot or legacy boot?

Comment: For Ubuntu you do not need a separate partition for / and home, you can have only a large / partition only.  It is nicer to have two but not needed.  If deleting windows, you can make life easy and use first option on ubuntu installer to erase and use whole disk.

Comment: I'm not deleting windows, so i'm just gonna make a big / partition, thanks both of you  :)

Comment: Go in Windows and shrink windows partition as much as possible, leaving enough free space.  Use windows tools for windows partitions to prevent troubles.  Then you can install ubuntu in new partition.